# Yahoo email account deletion

Tags: email, yahoo

On October 22, 2022 I deleted my yahoo email account and have not logged in. Three months from then is December 22, 2022.  I periodically send it an email to see if I get an error message that it was undeliverable, but do not, which tells me that other’s sending emails to it think I’m getting them.  I have contacted everyone who I “want” to have my new email but would also like others to get a message stating the email to yahoo account did not go thru.  It’s now 1/9/24.  Any idea when Yahoo will be actually deleting accounts?  I read it was done in August of 2023.

Comment: Sorry to hear about this. Unfortunately only Yahoo can know why they are still accepting messages. It could be a bug or some other reason. Please reach out to them for support.